# nullreferenceexception : unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i just started working in unity3d.
i have this class

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    private Rigidbody rb;
    void start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
        void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
        rb.AddForce(movement); 
    }
}
```

**it displays an error :**

> NullReferenceException: Object Reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      line : 11 {rb.AddForce(movement)}

please share if anyone knows what's the problem and how to solve it.

Comment: Gonna guess that `rb` is null so you're `start` method is either not being called, or `GetComponent` is returning null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wrote the start method with a small "s". So it is not called by Unity engine.

void Start() will work. Notice the capital "S".

Comment: yeah!! it worked....

Comment: Glad I could help! Don't forget to mark as answer!